# How to FTP into a virtual machine?

Tags: python, django, ftp, virtualenv, virtualbox

I've recently started learning Django and have set up a virtual machine running a Django server on VirtualEnv. I can use the runserver command to run the basic Django installation server and view it on another computer with the local IP address.

However, I can't figure out how to connect to my virtual machine with my FTP client so that I can edit files on my host machine (Windows). I've tried using the IP address of the virtual machine with an FTP client but it says "Connection refused by server".

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what OS are you running? how is your virtualmachine connected to your host os?

Comment: Have you installed an FTP server on your virtual machine?  Do you know if one is installed?

Comment: This question was migrated to Server Fault despite the fact that there are two comments making it *glaringly obvious* that there's not enough information here for us to help.  If you would like help with this question you need to provide (at a bare minimum) the items requested in the comments above.  See also [this meta question on writing good questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the the client reported back "Connection refused by server" is that the server returned a TCP packet with the reset bit set, in response to an application trying to connect to a port that is not being listened on by an application, or by a firewall.

I think that the FTP service is not running, or running on an alternate port.  Take a look at the output from `netstat -nltp` (on Linux) or `netstat -ntlb` (on windows).  You should see a program that is waiting to hear request on TCP port 21.  If you don't see the program listed at all or not on the expected port that your client is going to try and connect to, then modify the FTP servers configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to figure it out. For some reason the FTP server wasn't starting, running the restart script got it working.